# How can I add padding beneath an HTML button?

Tags: html, css

If my layout is

```
BUTTON
TEXT
```

I'm trying to create room between BUTTON and TEXT.  Trying something like

```
.bottom-gap {
    padding-bottom: 150px
}
```

Only seems to increase the height of the button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Padding is applied to the *inside* of the element. To add a *margin* to the bottom of the element, you need to use `margin-bottom: 150px`. I'm assuming your button is an actual UI `<button>` element. If not, you need to make sure it's displayed as an inline-block.